# Insert same ID in two differents tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently making an app in PHP for an online quizz.

I created 3 differents tables:

- 1 test (with test id, difficulty, time needed, and the subject of the test)
- 2 question (with the question)
- 3 reponse (answers)

When I'm creating an new test, I use this query :

```
$insert = $bdd->prepare(

  'INSERT INTO test (`test_ID`,`test_name`,`test_skills`, `test_level`, `test_time`, `test_creation`)

  VALUES (null, :test_name, :skills_ID, :level_ID, :time_ID, NOW());

  INSERT INTO question (`question_id`,`question_question`)

  VALUES ( ?????, :question_question)');
```

I would like to know how can I use the same ID in both tables in the same query. I tried to use `LAST_INSERT_ID` but it doesn't work.

I just need to get the value of "null" to reuse it just after.

Comment: Use 2 queries and put them inside a transaction

Comment: Are you using the `mysqli_` or `PDO` database extension?

Comment: Hi  riggsFolly. Thx for your help. I'm using PDO. I don't exactly know transaction, but I'm gonna look for this. Thx

Comment: Also look at [`PDO::lastInserId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)